# How to convert custom KV data type to BigQuery TableRow data type in Apache Beam

Tags: join, types, apache-beam

In Apache Beam, how to convert data in **<KV<Integer, KV<String, Integer>>>**
format to GCP BigQuery **TableRow** format using Java. Please let me know if anyone have the solution, thanks.

Want to know if there is any approach in converting data types from key value pairs to bigquery TableRow data type.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create your own [DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms) to convert KV to a TableRow, and use it with `ParDo`. For example:

```java
public class ConvertToTableRow extends DoFn<KV<Integer, KV<String, Integer>>, TableRow> {
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(@Element KV<Integer, KV<String, Integer>> input, OutputReceiver<TableRow> out) {

    Integer id = input.getKey();
    KV<String, Integer> record = input.getValue();

    TableRow row = new TableRow()
        .set("id", id)
        .set("name", ...);

    out.output(row);
  }
}
```

And then use it with a ParDo, for example:

```java
PCollection<KV<Integer, KV<String, Integer>> input = ...;

PCollection<TableRow> tableRows = input.apply("ConvertToTableRow", ParDo.of(new ConvertToTableRow());
```

Comment: As Bruno says, it's necessary to transform the collection into `TableRow` using custom logic. You may want to use the higher-level [MapElements](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/elementwise/mapelements/) transform to avoid some of the boilerplate of DoFn and ParDo.